# How to make a window in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I know this is going to sound confusing but I am making a to-do app for iOS, what I want to do is when a user taps on the add button, instead of user going to another view controller to enter in the new tasks information, I want a little window to pop up in that same view controller where the user can then enter the information. Is their a way to do this?

Comment: Can you please post, what you have tried yet? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You're looking for something like pop-up dialog, make a google search

Comment: @LucaNicoletti Thanks

Comment: @RichardWessels You can use the container View if you want to embed a controller in your view controller. That way you can still be on the same controller and add the information you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am not wrong you are talking about modal presentation where a view would appear over another view as a popup. This is how it can be done:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.storyboard(storyboard: .Vote).instantiateViewController(YourController.self)
```

under `YourController` use controller of the popup view

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
        let popover = nav.popoverPresentationController
        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 280,height: 300) //use own height and width
        vc.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        popover!.delegate = self

        popover!.sourceView = self.view
        popover!.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY - 20,width: 0,height: 0)
        popover!.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)

        self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

this will make the view appear as a popup in your root view